# add vb6 tool to arcmap 9.2 (on windows 7 64bit machine)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, tools, vb, arcgis-9.2

I have a vb6 project which develop a tool for use in arcmap several years ago. And I managed to add the tool in arcmap 9.2 (windows xp) by:

In arcmap -> Customize -> Add from file -> choose the dll file -> tool be added successfully.

But when I follow the same steps to add the tool in arcmap 9.2 (windows 7 64bit), I get "No new objects added".

I want to check is there a way to add a vb6 tool to arcmap 9.2 on windows 7 64bit machine?

Answer (score 1):

ArcMap 9.2 was released in 2006, 3 years before the release of Windows7. So 9.2 does not support Windows7.

XP and ArcGIS 9.2 are both outdated technologies (9.2 was retired in 2012 and XP last year) so moving to the current versions might sound like an option.

Comment: Thanks GISGe, but I managed to install arcmap 9.2 and our application in windows 7 64bit, it also works. But no luck for a tool developed in vb6.